# Add attribute to main menu item

Tags: routes

In my project I would like to add the following attributes to my "Login" main menu item:

`data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"` (Am using the Bootstrap theme)

I checked out the [menu attribute module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) but it does not allow for these attributes.

Please is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this HOOK_menu_link_alter and add new attribute from there.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7

```
function MYMODULE_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
  if ($item['link_path'] == 'user/login') {
    $item['options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'modal';
    $item['options']['attributes']['data-target'] = '#login-modal';
  }
}
```

Note : Make sure you clear cache and are checking this for anonymous user.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [menu attribute module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes)

If you are in drupal 7
Just install and enable [menu attribute module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module then go to module directory and edit menu_attributes.module to add following lines to menu_attributes_menu_attribute_info() function

Before
return $info; line

```
//Added by ErangaJ 
$info['data-toggle'] = array(
'label' => t('Data toggle'),
'scope' => array(MENU_ATTRIBUTES_LINK, MENU_ATTRIBUTES_ITEM),
);
$info['data-target'] = array(
'label' => t('Data target'),
'scope' => array(MENU_ATTRIBUTES_LINK, MENU_ATTRIBUTES_ITEM),
);
```

Comment: You should never, ever change a contrib module code. Use alters to do this instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can use drupal module [Bootstrap login modal](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_login_modal)

> Adds a login and register link in the nav bar. Opens them in Bootstrap
>   Modals.
>
> This module is intended for use with the Bootstrap theme.
>
> By
>   default the login and register links are added to the navigation
>   region, but they can be moved on the block admin page.

Comment: Hi makbuk and welcome. Please try to prevent link-only answers and include a relevant part of the answer in your post, optionally providing a link for further reference. It will give the OP a better idea of what to expect and your post will contain it's value in case the link would go down.